# Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62427

Tags: selenium-webdriver

HI im using seleinum web deriver to apply some tests and im getting this error:

```
(node:4147) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62427
(node:4147) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zerexit code.
```

I tried to put in vagrant file

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 62427, host: 62427
```

but its firing this errors:

```
ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:57807
ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54991
```

always with a different port

thanks in advance
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution on this issue

[Running node js selenium test case on Chrome get Error Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:63528](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827413/running-node-js-selenium-test-case-on-chrome-get-error-error-econnrefused-conne)

i have applied the same and it works.

Many thanks
Carlos Vieira